# How to set a custom color to WindowBackground

Tags: android, colors

I want to know how I can to set a custom color because when I put a color background in lollipop theme this say me to this color is not allowed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>


<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF0099</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF0099</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
     which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#339900</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">#f06292</item>

    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight, and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

</style>

</resources>
```

And I have the issue to say me error: Error: Color types not allowed (at '`android:windowBackground`' with value '#f06292'). I don't know what I must do.

And a last thing is to how can to call to all this function from code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using color as resource. So define it inside your strings xml file (or add your own colors xml file) like this:

```
<color name="yourcolor">#f06292</color>
```

and then change your error line to the following:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/yourcolor</item>
```

Comment: Thanks. Strange that direct usage did not work but via referencing it works, lol android :D